# Service method or domain static method in Grails?

Tags: oop, grails, groovy

This is a design question:

- when do I need to create/use a static method (in a domain class for instance)
- when do I need to create/use a service instead?

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method is to do only with the behaviour/details of the domain class then I'd make it a method on the domain (not necessarlily a static one). If it is more related to business logic then I'd put it in a service.

cheers

Lee

Comment: Hi,
I have a method that builds dynamically a google chart URL out of a DB request related to one domain. So, in that case what kind of method (service, static method of the domain class, helper method in the view...) would you have created ?

Comment: create a service. Static methods are harder to mock out. And eventually, if you want to have transactions, its easier to do it in a service.

Comment: Thx...but how can I access this service method from a view (for a domain static method, it is ok) ? When declaring `def helpersService`, it doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds like you should use a tagLib that gets injected with your service.